# How to run django and wordpress on NGINX server using same domain?

Tags: php, python, django, wordpress, nginx

I have tried many ways but do not know how to  run **Django on example.com** and **wordpress on example.com/blog**

The following running project directory structure for Django and Wordpress.

**Django app dir**- /home/ubuntu/django

**Django app running successfully on** - example.com:8000

**Wordpress dir** - /var/www/html/blog

**Wordpress running successfully on** - example.com

**Nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**Note-** Django app running by gunicorn, I know the subdomain may be the solution but I do not want that.

How to write nginx configuration for both Wordpress and Django to run **Django app** on example.com and **Wordpress** on example.com/blog ?

Comment: try subdomains `wordpress.example.com`, `blog.example.com` - in one file `server_name wordpress.example.com;` and in other `server_name blog.example.com;`

Comment: you need `location /blog` for PHP ?

Comment: my config for Gunicorn which works on localhost:3001 - you have to change port (and `server_name`). http://pastebin.com/4cc2vEKj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks  [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932938/alex) for helping me out to solve this problem.

Here is the solution

**Django app dir**- /home/ubuntu/django

**Wordpress dir** - /var/www/html/blog

**NGINX Conf file**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For          

            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~ /blog/.*\.php$ {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            set $php_root /var/www/html/blog;

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /blog {
            root /var/www/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            set $php_root /var/www/html/blog;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
    }

location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/django/your_app_name/static/static_root/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/django/your_app_name/media/ ;
    }

}
```

**Note-** please replace your home and siteurl with **http://example.com/blog** in wp-location table of wordpress

Now Your Django app running on example.com

Now Your Blog running on example.com/blog

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you have a server running your django site and one running your wordpress site. if so you can do something like this:

```
{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:(wordpress port);
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

if you need to server the php blog from ngix no apache in the middle use somethon like:

```
location ~ /blog/.*\.php$ {
    root /var/www/html/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $php_root /var/www/html/blog;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: if i use `proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;`  for django  and `proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;`  for wordpress then example.com opens Django but example.com/blog/ says page not found error from django side?

Comment: Sorry example.com/blog/ says  502 Bad Gateway, I think it is not serving php files

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway means the server that's back-proxied didn't respond, are you running your blog on apache?

Comment: One thing i noticed is that it seams like your trying to use port 80 to run both apache and nginx, if so change apache to other port.

Comment: it think i finally get what your trying to do: your going to server the php blog on nginx no apache in the middle right ?.

Comment: Yes I am not using apache, using nginx for both django and wordpress

Comment: Try to use the new location ~ /blog/.*\.php$  {...} configuration i posted (posted on an edit to this answer), delete the old  location /blog/ {...}

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines to your config file.

```
location ~ /blog/.*\.php$ {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location /blog {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}
```